# How to get Accounting "Closing date" in QuickBooks Online

Tags: python, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I want to retrieve information about Accounting "Closing date".
Found [here](https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D5G000004Dk7C5KAJ/how-can-i-get-closing-date-of-quick-books-online-company-through-api) that it is present in [Entitlements entity](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/entitlements).

But looks like it is not supported by this library.

Is there any other way to get Accounting "Closing date".

Initial problem, I'm getting the following error when creating Bill or Invoice:

```json
{
    "error_code": "5010", 
    "detail": "The account period has closed. {1}", 
    "message": "Account Period Closed"
}
```

Also created [issue on StackOverflow](https://github.com/ej2/python-quickbooks/issues/208) for that in [python-quickbooks](https://github.com/ej2/python-quickbooks) library that I use to access data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Preferences`](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/preferences#the-preferences-object) entity for that. It contains `AccountingInfoPrefs.BookCloseDate`.

Currently, it doesn't fully support by [`python-quickbooks`](https://github.com/ej2/python-quickbooks) yet (see [this open PR](https://github.com/ej2/python-quickbooks/pull/210), but you can use [this fork](https://github.com/wowkin2/python-quickbooks/tree/entity_preferences) that has implemented Preferences. You can install it using:

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/wowkin2/python-quickbooks.git@entity_preferences
```

P.S. Watch out for `minorversion` you use to initialize `QuickBooks()` object, it should be at least **`minorversion=21`**.